# html select (dropdown) control selected index changed event in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, webforms

I am trying to put backend code to my html select control (dropdown) when the value is changed a backend method to be triggered, but I Can't find the event.
I tried this way:

```
<select id="ddlCompany" name="select2" onchange="ddlCompany_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server" class="dropdown nostyle sel1" style="width:100%;" placeholder="Select Company" />
```

nothing changes.
Can anyone advice how I can fix this?
Thx, Laziale

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the SelectedIndexChanged property instead of onchange, like this:

```
<select id="ddlCompany" name="select2" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCompany_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server" class="dropdown nostyle sel1" style="width:100%;" placeholder="Select Company" />
```

Comment: So I tried both your and The Vanilla Thrilla's answers and neither of them worked, this is not an aspx or .net control... how then can it call C# methods?

Comment: Are you saying that what you are trying to use is not an aspx or .net control? If so, then this answer won't work.

Comment: well there isn't such a thing as OnSelectedIndexChanged in the properties menu in Visual Studio so I assume it isn't a .net or aspx control... I also cannot see any other Select control anywhere

Answer (score 5):

Add this to your code behind:

```
protected void ddlCompany_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //code here
}
```

And this to your markup:

```
OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCompany_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True"
```

Comment: The `AutoPostBack` helped me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the dropdownlist server control. Go to the designer view, Select the dropdownlist server control and right click and select **Properties**. Now in the properties window, click on the ***Events*** icon and then you can see the `SelectedIndexChanged` event. Double click on the blank white space on the right side and Visual studio will generate the relevant code for you.

[image]

Comment: @Shvju this is not dropdown control, its html select control. Thanks