# asp.net html select tag selected changet or autopostback

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

asp.net html select tag selected changed or autopostback not working.

```
<select class="input form-control" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Select1_SelectedIndexChanged" onserverclick="Select1_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server" id="Select1" name="Select1">
```

```
protected void Select1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    Response.Redirect("/urunler/kategori/"+Select1.Value); 
}
```

Comment: When you add runat="server" to an HTML control, it becomes a server side control which may not expose lot of events. In order to get richer server-side events, you need to use the ASP.NET controls. In your case a dropdownlist would work better which has events you are looking for. Nonetheless I found another question on SO similar to the issue you posted here -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16112218/html-select-dropdown-control-selected-index-changed-event-in-asp-net

Comment: I agree with @Kishore , it's better to use an aspx control when you are making it server side. all aspx controls are basically wrappers around html, programmed precisely to hook up with the aspx engine.